# multiple parameters not getting passed when I start my spring boot application in command line

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to override certain properties during deployment of my spring boot application.

when I try the following it works

`sudo /etc/init.d/myapp start --app.env=prod`

I see the `app.env` is correctly set to prod (my `/health` just echoes this values)

however when I set more than one property it did not work,

`sudo /etc/init.d/myapp start --app.env=prod --version=2.3.4`

I see only app.env is correctly set. the version value is not overridden.

why is it so? what is the right way to pass multiple parameters.

NOTE: I want to pass username and password for datasources. but for testing purposes, I kept it simple to override these properties.

Comment: Have you considered using JVM params? e.g sudo /etc/init.d/myapp start -Dapp.env=prod -Dversion=2.3.4

Comment: @AdamSmith: that did not work with even for a single parameter passing.

Comment: Have you considered putting those parameters into environment-specific configuration files (e.g. `application-prod.properties` and `application-test.properties`). You can then start your application with a single parameter `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod`. This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to read the section around [Customizing the startup script](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-script-customization). Specifically that you can include a myapp.conf file beside the jar file. In that .conf file is a `JAVA_OPTS` variable. You would then use `-Dapp.env=prod -Dversion=2.3.4`

Comment: I know about myapp.conf file. but setting there is not a possibility for me. I need to pass these in commandline (jenkins starts the service).

Comment: Why can't you have jenkins prop the myapp.conf prior to calling the service to start?

Comment: Reading around and it looks like JAVA_OPTS as an environment variable is also honored so you could have Jenkins set that environment variable prior to starting the service.